# Bash - Out of quotes to complete command

Tags: bash

I have run into this issue many times before and have always found an alternative way to write my command.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I xx sh -c 'stat -c%y xx | awk "BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $1}"'
```

The issue is that `FS=" "` is actually closing out the `"` before `BEGIN` and I can not use `'` because its encapsulating the entire command for `xargs`

Since `'` and `"` are the only quotes I have access to, how can I make the above work?

**EDIT:**
escaping did not work for me this time

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I xx sh -c 'stat -c%y xx | awk "BEGIN{FS=\"+\"}{print $2}"'
2014-04-12 22:34:47.000000000 +0000
2014-11-25 04:05:39.000000000 +0000
2015-02-07 09:23:42.000000000 +0000
2014-04-12 22:32:55.000000000 +0000
2014-04-12 22:33:59.000000000 +0000
2014-08-03 07:27:28.000000000 +0000
2014-04-12 22:32:03.000000000 +0000
2014-04-12 22:30:56.000000000 +0000
```

Even though I want to split on the spaces, I chose `+` so there is no confusion between a space or a tab.

Comment: Wouldn't this single command work for you? `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `find` command to this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' |
     xargs -I xx sh -c "stat -c '%y' file | awk '{print \$1}'"
```

Take note of `\$1` which is needed since `awk` is inside `sh -c` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just change FS=" " to FS=\" \"

'+' is special, in awk and several other regex implementations it means 1 or more characters.

You will need to escape + with \\+ as it is inside double quotes.

It is a bit difficult to understand what you want your script to actually do.

If you just want the modification date (YYYY-dd-mm) of the files in current directory, then you can do it with:

find . -maxdepth 1 -exec stat -c%y {} ';'

Beware that stat(1) is different on different unices.

Answer (score 0):

In `sh`/`bash`, you can escape a double-quote within a double-quoted string by preceding it with a backslash. In your `bash` context, the string is single-quoted, so you can add a backslash prior to each doubly-nested double-quote, and it will be preserved in the `bash` context (because single-quoted strings don't touch *anything* in the string during parsing), and in the `sh` context, the backslash-followed-by-double-quote will be properly escaped within the outer double-quoted string.

Ah, and there's a second problem: the `$1` is being interpolated as a variable substitution within the outer double-quoted string (i.e. the `awk` argument), which is expanding to nothing, so your `awk` command ends up just calling `print` with no arguments, which prints the whole input line. You can solve this by backslash-escaping the dollar as well. So:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I xx sh -c 'stat -c%y xx | awk "BEGIN{FS=\" \"}{print \$1}"'
```